# Cloudvault client cannot establish connection due to certificate problems

Tags: certificate

I'm getting `CloudVaultCertificateException` with message `Certificate found, but cannot access private key` when trying to upload files.

Here is the stacktrace

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Infra.CloudVault.Library.Client.Exceptions.CloudVaultCertificateException: Certificate found, but cannot access private key.
   at Microsoft.Infra.CloudVault.Library.Client.ExceptionHandler.LogAndThrowException(String message, TofuTagId tagId, Exception ex, Boolean isRetryable) in C:\rd\EngSys\DevServices\CloudVault\src\Library\Client\Exceptions\ExceptionHandler.cs
   at Microsoft.Infra.CloudVault.Library.Client.PartitionUploader.Upload() in C:\rd\EngSys\DevServices\CloudVault\src\Library\Client\Upload\PartitionUploader.cs
   at Microsoft.Infra.CloudVault.Library.Client.Uploader.PartitionedUpload(String targetDir, String fileFilter, String tempDir, String vaultType, Dictionary`2 metadata, String waitSignalPath, Boolean useFastIndexing, String[] watchExcludedPaths, SearchOption directoryRecursion, List`1 certificates, String configDirectory, Boolean useSymbolicLinks) in C:\rd\EngSys\DevServices\CloudVault\src\Library\Client\Upload\Uploader.cs
   at Microsoft.Infra.CloudVault.Library.Client.CloudVaultManager.PartitionedUpload(String targetDir, String fileFilter, String tempDir, String vaultType, Dictionary`2 metadata, String configDirectory, String waitSignalPath, Boolean disableSymbolicLinks) in C:\rd\EngSys\DevServices\CloudVault\src\Library\Client\CloudVaultManager.cs 
   at Microsoft.Infra.CloudVault.Library.CommandLine.EntryPoint.Execute() in C:\rd\EngSys\DevServices\CloudVault\src\Library\CommandLine\EntryPoint.cs
```

Whats wrong with the cert and what do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

**CloudVault** client uses certificate to establish connection with service, that's why certificate must be properly installed on your local machine.

Here are steps to properly install certificate.

1. First of all you need to import cert in `*.pfx` format, not *.cer and enter password for private key during importing.
2. You need to choose `Local Machine` as a store location for cert
3. Cert must be installed into `Personal` store, which will be used by default if you leave Automatic store selection
4. And the last important thing which actually causes that exception is CloudVault client must have access to cert's private key

You can fix this either by running CloudVault client with admin rights or manually adding right to the private key. I recommend second way.

You need to run **mmc** from Run, *File*->*Add/Remove Snap-in*, double click Certificates and choose *Computer account*->*Local computer*.
Open Personal Certificates, find cert, right click on it and select *All Tasks*->*Manage Private Keys* and add Permissions to user that is used to run CloudVault client.